# Label/filter mail sent to specific recipient (or whole domain) on Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'm planning on deleting a very old domain I never use other than quite a lot as various email addresses on websites, services, etc.:  `hello@example.com`, `anything@example.com`, etc.

As it is, all email sent to that domain are forwarded to my Gmail account.

Can I mark/label/filter/sort incoming mail in Gmail, so that all mail originally sent to `xxxxx@example.com` will have some visible mark, or be sorted somehow?

Then I can see it and go to that website/service and change my email address, before I delete my domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple filter for `to:(@example.com)` should do what you need. Simply create a filter on that and apply the label you want. You'll also have the option to "Also apply filter to **XXX** matching conversations" so you can label any of the messages you've already received.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, thank you. It was quite easy. I just made it star-mark mails sent to mydomain.com